# MATLAB, fixed point iteration

Tags: matlab, iteration, root

I am given a function, f(x)= 5*sin(x)*exp(-x-0.2)-1, and I want to find a root using fixed point iteration. The instruction told me to re-arrange the equation to get x=g(x).

So I converted it to x=-ln[1/(5sin(x)]-0.2

I want to make a while loop that satisfies x(1+i)=g(i) relationship as I update x, until x converges. I am guessing that the 'converging' here means that abs(x(i)-x(i+1)) is very small, but not so sure.

```
x(1)=1;
while abs(x(i+1)-x(i)>0.0001 && i<50
    g(i)=-log(1/(5*sin(x(i))))-0.2;
    x(i+1)=g(i);
end
```

My code is obviously wrong. I know I have to update i like, i=i+1; somewhere, but I don't know how I should apply it. also, I see that I haven't declared x(1+1) in  the beginning, and that's where I am getting an error from, but... no clue how to fix it.

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in a while loop, then you need to do the first iteration outside the while loop:

```
x(1) = 1;
x(2) = -log(1/(5*sin(x(1)))) - 0.2;
i = 2;
max_iter = 50;
while (abs(x(i) - x(i-1)) > 0.0001) && (i < max_iter)
   x(i+1) = -log(1/(5*sin(x(i)))) - 0.2;
   i = i + 1;
end
```

Alternatively you could test for the number of elements of x in the while condition but that less elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Put the test for convergence inside the loop since you have only one value of x to start with:

```
x(1) = 1;
max_iter = 50;
for i = 1 : max_iter
    x(i+1) = -log(1/(5*sin(x(i)))) - 0.2;
    if abs(x(i+1) - x(i)) < 0.0001
        break; end
end
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can do it with a while loop? I knew how to do it with for loop, but I think I didn't make it clear